# Environment variables not being set after configuring Nginx and Gunicorn (Django app on Ubuntu machine)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I just set up Gunicorn with Nginx (reverse proxy) for a Django web app. The combo seems to be firing up correctly as per `gunicorn.log`. Note that I'm not using supervisor.

But curiously, my **environment variables** (set in `.profile`) aren't being picked up at all! `printenv` shows they exist. Some things I've tried are putting the environment variables in `/etc/default/nginx` and restarting nginx, in `etc/environment`, in `.profile`, in `nginx.conf`, in `gunicorn.conf`, etc. It just doesn't work!

By the way, it worked perfectly *before* installing and configuring nginx, i.e. when I was simply running: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings myproject.wsgi:application`.

Now it seems that nginx:

> removes all environment variables inherited from its parent process
>   except the TZ variable

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env Could this be the reason why nothing I'm trying has come close to working? But if so, these variables added to nginx.conf ought to have been picked up I suppose. Nevertheless, using `echo $envvar` yields the correct value on the command line, which tells me that perhaps the variables are set, but **being bypassed or overlooked**. Note that the `USER` env variable shows up as **None** too, whereas print `TERM` prints **linux**.

---

**wsgi.py**:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

**gunicorn.conf:**

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid myuser
setgid www-data
chdir /home/myuser/directory/myproject/

exec /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/gunicorn --chdir=/home/myuser/directory/ --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/directory/myproject/myproject.sock --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings myproject.wsgi:application
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.cloudapp.net;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myuser/directory/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/directory/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

*Note: ask me for more information in case you need it.*

Comment: Can we see the "app" launch code (usually called `wsgi.py`) and how you call it (`gunicorn ...`), and any other source thats not secret. More details like, what is the "user" that runs the code, and if you're using supervisord it would be nice to know. -- any more details how the code is ran would be useful too

Comment: Does nginx "run" gunicorn or merely uses a socket/port and proxies it? If it "uses" it then i don't need to see your nginx conf. If it does "run" it then, yes.

Comment: The only think i can see/ think of is that your myuser doesnt have the environment variables you speak of. Try this: sudo su myuser && env if they're there; we have another issue, if they're not, you need to add it to THAT user's profile, NOT your current logged in-as user

Comment: `usermod -d /home/myuser myuser` and then just add it there `vim /home/myuser/.profile` -- you can always just add it into your `gunicorn.conf` if they're not too many of them.. Up to you.

Comment: You're saying that this `sudo su myuser && env` works now? and that gunicorn is not picking it up?

Comment: If I run `sudo su myuser && env`, nothing happens, I merely go to the next line (that's ok behavior?). If I do `sudo su myuser` and then `printenv`, the printed output shows me my variables are indeed part of the environment (they're currently added to `/etc/environment` which sets them globally). BTW I've tried gunicorn.conf too (after trying .profile originally). Nothing works. A clue is that according to docs, nginx removes all variables inherited (except TZ): http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env Could this be it? But I tried setting them in nginx.conf too; that failed as well.

Comment: I tried to get the `USER` environment variable in my settings.py and printed it. It came out as `None`. `printenv` shows me `USER=myuser` whether I switch the user or not (I only set up one user for this installation any way). I'm beginning to believe USER being None is the sympton of the actual problem, one that doesn't go away even if I do `usermod -d /home/myuser myuser` and add the variables accordingly. Even trying to set them globally didn't work (`/etc/environment`). Someone in my office suggested I install supervisor. That might work, but it doesn't still answer why this set up fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So an air-tight (hopefully) way of setting environment variables that gunicorn would have no trouble seeing is editing gunicorn.conf as follows:

`exec /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/gunicorn --chdir=/home/myuser/directory/ --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/directory/myproject/myproject.sock -e var1=value1 -e var2=value2 myproject.wsgi:application`

This has served me well so far. If I run into any issues, I'll update this answer.