# How to set up globally visible environment variables on Azure VM (v1)

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, azure, nginx

Is there a way to set system wide/globally visible environment variables on an Azure VM (service management) with Ubuntu OS? I'm stuck in a situation where setting them inside ubuntu's `/etc/environment` `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` isn't being picked up by my application code. However, they do show up on `printenv`. My guess is they're somehow getting bypassed because of the way my webserver is set up (Gunicorn + Nginx reverse proxy).

But maybe there's a way to set up env variables on Azure VMs that that takes precedence over everything? I know Heroku has that option in their dashboard (I've been using it), so do Azure Web Apps (which I'm not able to use due to a variety of well-documented compatibility issues).

Comment: On my Azure VM with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, I set `export TEST=abc` in `/etc/profile` and follow the installation content at http://gunicorn.org/ to run the code `myapp.py` modified by adding `import os` and `print os.environ['TEST']` in the function `app`. I can get the environment variable in the console when I command `w3m http://localhost:8000` to access the url. Any more about your issue for helping resolve it?

Comment: Hi Hassan Baig. I followed the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181555/environment-variables-not-being-set-after-configuring-nginx-and-gunicorn-django to do again, and these environment variables in ubuntu common `/etc/*` canbe picked up by code. However, I think you can try to run the command `source /etc/profile /etc/...`(these `/etc` files what you want) firstly before startup application on the same session.

Comment: You mean I try `sudo service gunicorn stop`, then *source* those files, and then `sudo service gunicorn start`? Or something else? I even tried restarting my Azure VM from the portal. One clue I have is that if I try to print the default environment variable `USER`, the value printed is `None`, even if I'm logged in with **root**, or **myuser**.

Comment: Yes, `source` those file before start `gunicorn`. And you can add the cmd `source ...` into the service bash script `gunicorn` at the path `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: I don't have a gunicorn bash script in `/etc/init.d/`, I have an nginx bashscript though, where I already added `export my_variable=value`. Shouldn't this have worked? Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As references, I post my steps on Azure VM. You can check them and compare with yours.

1. Connect to a new Azure VM: `ssh user@vm-name.cloudapp.net`
2. Install the tool `pip` and `virtualenv`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python-pip
   sudo pip install virtualenv
   ```
3. Preparing the virtualenv to install `gunicorn` and `django`

   ```
   mkdir environments
   virtualenv environments/experiment/ 
   cd environments/experiment/ 
   source bin/activate 
   pip install gunicorn django
   ```
4. Create a django project and run it by using `gunicorn` and try to access it:

   ```
   django-admin startproject mysite
   bin/gunicorn --chdir=mysite -w 3 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings mysite.wsgi:application
   # using w3m to access http://localhost:8000
   w3m http://localhost:8000
   ```
5. Install Nginx and configure reverse proxy:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nginx
   sudo cp /etc/nginx/site-available/default /etc/nginx/site-available/default.bak
   sudo vim /etc/nginx/site-available/default
   ```

The configured content in the `default` file for nginx below:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/<user>/environments/experiment/mysite/mysite.sock; 
                # I also try to config `http://localhost:8000;`, it's ok too.
        }
  }
```

I also try to config `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;`, it's ok too.

6. Restart `nginx` service and restart `gunicorn`:

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart
   bin/gunicorn --chdir=mysite --bind unix:/home/<user>/environments/experiment/mysite/mysite.sock -w 3 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings mysite.wsgi:application
   ```

And I found the application can't get the environment variables set up after application startup. So please run the command `source /etc/...` before `gunicorn` startup.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Tried all that, still didn't get it to work. Then I hard-coded the env variables just to see what happens next. I ended up getting a strange error: `DatabaseError at / invalid input syntax for type inet` Have you ever seen this before? There's not much documentation for it. I think I just might uninstall my setup and start again.

Comment: @HassanBaig What database you used? Dose the error show the position of bug codes? Does the settings code follow the syntax for database setup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#host)?

Comment: Actually, based on the questions in your comment, I ended up turning that into a separate SO post (since it's a separate issue). Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238623/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-inet-db-error-in-django-app-with-postgres-and-gu Meanwhile, this answer of yours worked, thanks! Accepting it and upvoting.