# 'Invalid input syntax for type inet' db error in Django app with postgres and Gunicorn+Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

Can you help me decipher this rather esoteric error? Everything's fine when I fire up the application, but crashes the moment I try to `login`.

> DatabaseError at /login/
>
> invalid input syntax for type inet: "" LINE 1: ...00101 Firefox/41.0',
>   '2015-12-12 09:39:55.590036+00:00', '')
>
> Exception Location:
>     /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py
>   in execute, line 54

I know for a fact that the [inet data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET) accepts IPv4 and IPv6 hosts and networks (but not domain names).

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  187.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/user_sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  46.                     request.session.save()
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/user_sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  86.                     obj.save(force_insert=must_create, using=using)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  650.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  215.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1661.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  937.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  58.             six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  54.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /login/
Exception Value: invalid input syntax for type inet: ""
LINE 1: ...00101 Firefox/41.0', '2015-12-12 09:39:55.590036+00:00', '')
```

The **/login/** url in urls.py is `url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name="login"),`

The environment is:

**Django 1.5.1** with a **postgresql backend** and resides on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Especially note that this error started coming after I set up *nginx as a reverse proxy behind gunicorn* (using port 80 for this set up). Things worked **perfectly** when I used *solely* gunicorn (and waitress, another pure python web server) on port 8080.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.cloudapp.net;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/mhb11/folder/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mhb11/folder/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
   location = /500.html {
        root /home/mhb11/folder/myproject/templates/;
   }
}
```

/etc/nginx/proxy_params:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

env ON_AZURE=1;
env awsaccesskeyid=something;
env awssecretkey=something;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascrip$

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

What's going on?

*Note: please ask me for more information in case you need it, e.g. how my gunicorn.conf and nginx.conf looks, packages installed or if you need something db related. Just ask away!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not forwarding proxy IP. Here is my set of forwarded headers I set in my nginx config:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host                    $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    User-Agent              $http_user_agent;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
    proxy_pass          ......;
}
```

More options in nginx docs - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

Then in Django you can do:

```
user_ip = request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP`] or request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Note that `X-Forwarded-Proto` is necessary when using Django with SSL in which case you will also need to configure Django a bit:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

More in Django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER

Comment: `proxy_set_header` directive can only be used within `location` block as far as I know. I updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: usually in your `myproject.conf` file. although I usually put those directives into a separate file `proxy_params.conf` which I include in my `location` block via `include` directive but that is not necessary.

Comment: just hardcode them for now. that should start sending the correct headers to Django. if still does not work, then the issues is in Django. print out `request.META` to see all headers sent by nginx to Django

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR` will be empty. You will need to use `HTTP_X_REAL_IP`

Comment: Okay, so I'm writing a middleware to set `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] = request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` (or `request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`)`, so that any dependecies broken because of REMOTE_ADDR being ' ' are taken care of.

Comment: `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is wrong. it will be the IP of the proxy server which is nginx in your case

Comment: actually I was wrong. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will contain the real ip of the user however you will need to parse it since it will be comma separated list of ips, etc. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your program is trying to add a row to some logging table with empty remote IP. I suppose that when you use reverse proxy the program doesn't know the remote IP, as it's shadowed by proxy's IP.

As it's empty I suppose the program is trying to ignore proxy's IP, but it does not find any better. It should use `X-Forwarded-For` header.

If there's no reasonable IP to log, the program should simply log "NULL" as the IP.

Comment: Hmm okay,to try that, I should add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` file? Or should I add that to my nginx.conf? Please advise.

Comment: After carefully looking at what request.META is being passed from nginx to the Django app, I see that `REMOTE_ADDR `is ' ' (though `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` and `HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR` are correctly being set). Postgresql IPs are of the type INET, not string, and ' ' isn't an acceptable value (like you guessed too). How do I set a value for REMOTE_ADDR?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom middleware solved it:

```
class XForwardedForMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.has_key("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"):
            request.META["HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_ADDR"] = request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"]
            parts = request.META["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].split(",", 1)
            request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"] = parts[0]
```