# nginx is giving django-axes (access logging middleware) a null ip address

Tags: django, nginx

I'm having trouble accessing the login page of my site. It has `django-axes` access logging middleware watching it:

```
from axes.decorators import watch_login
@method_decorator(watch_login, name="dispatch")
class UserLogin(FormView): ...
```

A GET request to the login page results in:

> DataError at /path/to/login/
>
> invalid input syntax for type inet: "b''"

The ip address in the traceback (as per the error) is `b''`; so I guess the [nginx proxy is not passing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34241597/3790954).

Here's an extract of my nginx `sites-available` config (I have not enabled ssl while debugging this):

```
upstream app_servers {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass          http://app_servers;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    real_ip_header      X-Real-IP;
    proxy_set_header    Host                    $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    User-Agent              $http_user_agent;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
}
```

What am I missing from my nginx config to get `django-axes` working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability is that you have forgotten to set [`AXES_BEHIND_REVERSE_PROXY`](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#customizing-axes).  Setting that to `True` in your django settings should allow django-axes to see the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header.

> - `AXES_BEHIND_REVERSE_PROXY`: If `True`, it will look for the IP address 
>     from the header defined at `AXES_REVERSE_PROXY_HEADER`. Please make sure 
>     if you enable this setting to configure your proxy to set the correct 
>     value for the header, otherwise you could be attacked by setting this 
>     header directly in every request. Default: `False`
> - `AXES_REVERSE_PROXY_HEADER`: If `AXES_BEHIND_REVERSE_PROXY` is `True`,
>     it will look for the IP address from this header. Default:
>     `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Comment: That worked! Thank you; last time I used axes was 0.4 versions ago and it was not necessary to manually specify this at that time and I hadn't picked up on the change yet.

Answer (score 7):

Just an update if anyone comes across this problem now. AXES_BEHIND_REVERSE_PROXY has been [deprecated](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/10_changelog.html#id53).

The following setting has worked for me:

```
AXES_META_PRECEDENCE_ORDER = [
   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
   'REMOTE_ADDR',
]
```

The [docs](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_configuration.html#configuring-reverse-proxies) mention AXES_PROXY_COUNT as well. However, for my setup, leaving the default setting as None worked for me.

My Nginx settings are as follows:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```